# Azure Devops logging commands in release pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to customize the output of my pipeline release through setting some env variables into a task.
I found the following link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell

which however does not seem to work.
What I am doing is simply to create a pipeline with a single task (either bash or PS), and there declaring the commands specified in the link through the inline version of the task.

Has anyone already successfully managed to make these commands work?
Do I do something wrong and/or incomplete?

Does anyone have a better way to customise the pipeline with relevant information from a task? E.g. through the release name, or the description and/or tag of the specific release?

*Edit:*

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=sauce;]crushed tomatoes"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=secretSauce;issecret=true]crushed tomatoes with garlic"

Write-Host "Non-secrets automatically mapped in, sauce is $env:SAUCE"
Write-Host "Secrets are not automatically mapped in, secretSauce is $env:SECRETSAUCE"
Write-Host "You can use macro replacement to get secrets, and they'll be masked in the log: $(secretSauce)"
```

this is the code, copy and pasted. Now I tried also with the script, and it does not work either.
I use an hosted windows agent.

Comment: I've used them before and they work, you just have to be correct with the syntax. For example the `;` in the syntax is very important. What, exactly, you are executing?

Comment: Make sure you're doing it as specified in the documentation, `Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;]testvalue"` not `Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable testvar=testvalue;]"`

Comment: Can you share your bash/PS script

Comment: I just did copy and paste what's written in the documentation. Just to be clear, I do write everything directly inline, without uploading any bash/PS script. If you were successful with a script then this can be the key difference

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk I inserted the code. Please tell me if you have any other hint.

Comment: @Neo Check my answer below :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you set a new variable with the logging command the variable is available only in the **next** tasks and not in the same task.

So, split your script to 2 tasks, in the second task put the last 3 lines and you will see that the first task works:

[image]

Comment: Why does the release log `##[section]Finishing: PowerShell Script copy`? According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops) it should log `Finishing: PowerShell Script copy` in green.

Answer (score 0):

this also puzzled me for a while, in the end i found out that if you want to modify the $env:path you can call the special task called task.prependpath by using the special logging command syntax like "##vso[task.prependpath]local directory path". you can find more of this kind of special commands from their source :
https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md

Comment: Welcome and thank you for your contribution! Right now your answer is rather difficult to read due to unformatted code snippets. Might I suggest to check out [how do I format my posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and edit your answer accordingly? :-)